# Github README suddenly not appearing properly

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

The README.md files are suddenly not appearing properly on my repositories hosted on Github.

https://github.com/kensplanet/dev-dictionary

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't place markdown inside HTML.

You were wrapping a markdown image with: `<kbd></kbd>`, rather use an HTML `<img>` tag inside other HTML. That is why you were seeing text and not your image.

Further, use markdown instead of HTML where possible, as the markdown processor can often make mistakes.

Here is the corrected markdown file:

```html
<h1 align="center">Dev Dictionary</h1>
<p align="center">Find information on any technology</p>
<kbd><img src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4705188/20508600/ac62b414-b030-11e6-9dfe-691a6a3250fd.png" alt="image">
</kbd>

## Overview
This is the repository of **Dev Dictionary**, a Chrome Extension to help developers find information on any technology. It can be installed through the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-dictionary/mbhildcgplbobgnhgnihmeiaokhdaelf).

## Development
* For more information regarding development of Chrome extensions, see [Getting Started: Building a Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)
* For more information regarding Chrome extension APIs, see [Chrome Platform APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index)

## Libraries
* [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/)
* [Redux](http://redux.js.org/)
* [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)
* [Node JS](https://nodejs.org)
* [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
* [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)
```

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thanks. It used to work last month. Not sure if some changes were introduced recently.

Comment: "Not sure if some changes were introduced recently." In fact, GitHub Flavored Markdown [adopted a formal spec on March 14](https://github.com/blog/2333-a-formal-spec-for-github-flavored-markdown) that would have changed the way some pages render. I have noticed that they now require a space after opening ATX-style header markers (that is, `# Header` instead of `#Header`), which I believe is a good change. I'm sure there are others.